# How to mix Azure AD authentication and Windows authentication in MVC 4 app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, azure-active-directory

I have a design requirement for an ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET 4.6.1) app hosted on the company server (Not Azure) to do the following:

Check is user is authenticated via Windows Authentication

a)Yes - designate user as "authenticated"

b)No - use OpenIdConnect (OWIN) to authentication using Azure Active Directory.

Once authenticated use the standard [Authorize] attributes on controller methods etc. I have implemented Windows and Azure AD authentication alone is individual MVC apps but never together.

I have found several sources describing how to mix Windows and Forms authentication, but none for this combination.

Does anyone have insights on how this might be achieved?

Comment: i have a vague recollection that if you do file | new project and create a new asp.net mvc project, the wizard lets you create a blank project with multiple authentication modes.

Comment: I checked this out and in VS2015 Update 3 it appears you can only select one authentication mode when creating the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement a year ago and my approach was :

The users are redirected to input their AD credentials (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/)

Once they are sucessfully logged in on the AD you will get a token.

Then I call the Azure AD API on their behalf using the token I just got. I woulds just call the **/me** endpoint that will return me the user personal details.

With the above response I just need to check if the email address matches the email address that was initially requested.

If it matches it means the user was successfully validated against the AD.

Then you can proceed and issue that user a token or cookie to access your application.

Comment: My requirement is slightly different than yours. When the user visits the site I want to determine if they are already authenticated by Windows and if so NOT display the Azure Ad login. If they are not authenticated by Windows then redirect to Azure AD login.

I have Azure AD authentication via OWIN working. Now I'm trying to figure out how to have mixed mode w/ Windows auth as well.